# Windows 10 and wpf bidning

Tags: wpf

does anyone knows if there is any issue binding data using windows 10 and visual studio 10 WPF project?
it should be very simple code line and i don't see any reason why the data is not binding
the data is biding in the xaml so i dont see other problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using WpfApplication2.ViewModel;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            WpfApplication2.MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            UserViewModel VM = new UserViewModel();
            window.DataContext = VM;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication2.ViewModel
{
    class UserViewModel
    {
        private IList<User> _UsersList;
        public UserViewModel()
        {
            _UsersList = new List<User>
            {
                new User{UserId = 1,FirstName="Raj",LastName="Beniwal",City="Delhi",State="DEL",Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=2,FirstName="Mark",LastName="henry",City="New York", State="NY", Country="USA"},
                new User{UserId=3,FirstName="Mahesh",LastName="Chand",City="Philadelphia", State="PHL", Country="USA"},
                new User{UserId=4,FirstName="Vikash",LastName="Nanda",City="Noida", State="UP", Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=5,FirstName="Harsh",LastName="Kumar",City="Ghaziabad", State="UP", Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=6,FirstName="Reetesh",LastName="Tomar",City="Mumbai", State="MP", Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=7,FirstName="Deven",LastName="Verma",City="Palwal", State="HP", Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=8,FirstName="Ravi",LastName="Taneja",City="Delhi", State="DEL", Country="INDIA"}            
            };
        }
        public IList<User> Users
        {
            get { return _UsersList; }
            set { _UsersList = value; }
        }
        private ICommand mUpdater;
        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (mUpdater == null)
                    mUpdater = new Updater();
                return mUpdater;
            }
            set
            {
                mUpdater = value;
            }
        }
        private class Updater : ICommand
        {
            #region ICommand Members
            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return true;
            }
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="485" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Name="UserGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,178,12,13"  ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"  >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="UserId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserId}"  Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"  Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="City" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}" Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="State" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State}" Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Country" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Country}" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtUserId" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.UserId}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,35,0,0" Name="txtFirstName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.FirstName}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,62,0,0" Name="txtLastName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserGrid,Path=SelectedItem.LastName}" />
        <Label Content="UserId" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,274" Name="label1" />
        <Label Content="Last Name" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,60,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="First Name" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,35,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Content="Update" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,40,0,0" Name="btnUpdate" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"
                Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommad}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,143,0,0" x:Name="txtCity" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.City, ElementName=UserGrid}" />
        <Label Content="Country" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,141,0,0" x:Name="label2_Copy" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,88,0,0" x:Name="txtCountry" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Country, ElementName=UserGrid}" />
        <Label Content="City" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,86,0,0" x:Name="label2_Copy1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,115,0,0" x:Name="txtSTate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.State, ElementName=UserGrid}" />
        <Label Content="State" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,113,0,0" x:Name="label2_Copy2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What are you binding your list to? Can you provide some xaml code

Comment: i updated my code now with the xaml.i think the problem was that namespace, when i place the databinding in the relevant window it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use ObservableCollection instead of List:

```
private ObservableCollection<User> _users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

public ObservableCollection<User> Users
{
    get { return _users; }
    set
    {
        _users= value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that OnPropertyChanged is just as important as the use of ObservableCollection here. Without property change notifications the UI will not update automatically when the collection changes.

Comment: @goobering you are right. I just didn't think that I should mention that. Next time I will

Answer (score 0):

As you are using 'IList' the problem is that the list initially is empty when binded to UI. The bindings take place when InitializeComponent() is called. Hence the ItemsSource property has to be updated.

```
 UserGrid.ItemsSource = Users;
```

Adding the above line will solve your problem.

It is better to use ObservableCollection instead of List, as it automatically updates the UI when any change has been made on the binded value.

Comment: You are wrong. He creates viewModel first, and then sets datacontext

Comment: It is necessary to bind the Itemssource again in order to update the UI as IList is used